# About the additive group and the multiplicative group of a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field. When happens that the additive group of $F$ is isomorphic to the multiplicative group?

It is easily to work out that $F$ must have characteristic $0$, but then what?

Comment: Consider the case of finite fields. Every finite field is of odd order, so there does not exist a non-trivial element $x$ such that $2x = 0$. But there will always exist a non-trivial $y$ such that $y \cdot y = 1$.

Comment: Not every finite field is of odd order...in fact, there are infinite finite fields of *even* order.

Comment: It is meant every finite field of characteristic not $2$ is of odd order. If the characteristic is $2$ then this argument fails to be valid since every element is of order $2$ in the additive group. However, clearly there is no group isomorphism between $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ and $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}^\times$ for any $n$ as they have different orders as groups. So the argument is valid.

Comment: @Eoin Thank you for that, I *assumed* what Myridium meant, I just remarked a careless phrase in that comment, that's all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already have that char$\,\Bbb F=0\;$ then what does $\;-1\;$ map to? This is an element of order two in $\;\Bbb F^*\;$ so it must map to an element of order two in $\;\Bbb F\;$ .

Comment: It was easy... Thanks!